How do I prevent AWS EC2 public IP from showing in Google Search?
I'm hosting a website on AWS EC2 and I have been fine tuning my configuration and SEO. All of the pages work, and my domain routing works properly. The issue I keep having is that when I look up my site on Google, I see results for both mydomain.com and my.public.ip.amazonaws.com. I am trying to prevent the latter from showing up and confusing users.
I have looked in to Google's crawling procedures and "robot.txt" rules to prevent crawling certain areas of the site (documentation). But if I create a noindex rule in there, I remove my whole site from Google. How do I prevent search engines from displaying content accessed via my server's IP, and only display content that routes through my domain?

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Your web server should be redirecting users to your canonical domain.
So, a request to my.public.ip.amazonaws.com should be a 301 redirect with:
Location: https://example.com/whatever


I applied this fix, following the documentation that @mark-b commented above. I'm linking it again here to make life easier for the next guy that has this issue.
